# ASP.NET 4.0 HiddenFields

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-4.0, hiddenfield

```
HiddenField hidCurrentFooterLinks = (HiddenField)gvTaxonomy.FindControl("hidCurrentFooterLinks");
hidCurrentFooterLinks.Value = txtFooterLinkCurrentYear.Text;
HiddenField hidPreviousFooterLinks = (HiddenField)gvTaxonomy.FindControl("hidPreviousFooterLinks");
hidPreviousFooterLinks.Value = txtFooterLinkPreviousYear.Text;
txtFooterLinkCurrentYear.Text = "";
txtFooterLinkPreviousYear.Text = "";
```

This is my code. I am getting Exception like `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow..this is Mayur Parekh :)

Comment: Do you really find `hidCurrentFooterLinks` or `hidPreviousFooterLinks` ?

Comment: You need to some debugging. follow the code through and find out which of the objects is nothing at the point of use. Probably the `FindControl` calls are not finding the control named and returning nothing, but without more information and debugging from you there's not much more to be said.

Comment: *Where* are you getting a `NullReferenceException`?  Wherever it is, that means an object, whose property you are trying to read or write, is null.

Comment: You need to give more detail than you have for us to help with this issue.  At the very least, you need to give us your mark up source which shows all the controls that are referenced in your code.  It would also be useful to know some more about the function that the included code is in - is it an event handler, Page_Load?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is the your controls have not been found, you need to make sure the control is found and a null reference not returned.

```
if ((hidCurrentFooterLinks != null) || (hidPreviousFooterLinks != null)) {  // DO SOMETHING   }
```

Comment: That error is coming because I am not able to find the hiddenField's control. So, will you please any one tell me that how can I find control for hidden fields.

Comment: Are the controls nested within another control, like an Ajax Update panel, any form of Data driven templated control like a a repeater?